# Reduce 2 variables in for loop?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I 'm uncertain if there is a way this could be done. My homework says so, but I was pretty sure there is no such way:

```
    CStringArray m_Last;
    int size = m_Last.GetCount();

    // In the .h file I have,

     #define IDM_LAST 90// these are to be used for contiguous Resource ID's
     const int MAXLAST = 5; // there are 5 Resource IDs

    for(int i = 0, j = IDM_LAST; i < size, j < IDM_LAST + MAXLASTUSEDDEST; ; i++, j++)
    {
        menuAPopup.AppendMenu(MF_STRING, j, m_Last.ElementAt(i));
    }
```

Here is there a way that I can just use 1 variable for the for loop, either `i` or `j`?

Comment: you've got a stray ';' after the loop terminating conditions

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
i < size, j < IDM_LAST + MAXLASTUSEDDEST
```

You need to change the `,` in the condition to an `&&`.

---

In short, here is how `for` works:

```
for (X; Y; Z)
{
    ...
}
```

translates to:

```
X;
while (Y)
{
    ...
    Z;
}
```

except variables defined in `X` will be in the scope of `while`.

Since the following is a valid C code:

```
int i = 0, j = IDM_LAST;
while (i < size && j < IDM_LAST + MAXLASTUSEDDEST)
{
    menuAPopup.AppendMenu(MF_STRING, j, m_Last.ElementAt(i));
    i++, j++;
}
```

then this `for` is also valid:

```
for(int i = 0, j = IDM_LAST; i < size && j < IDM_LAST + MAXLASTUSEDDEST; i++, j++)
{
    menuAPopup.AppendMenu(MF_STRING, j, m_Last.ElementAt(i));
}
```

---

You don't necessarily need to reduce the number of variables, but if you insist, here's how you would do it.

If you look closely, you will notice that `j` is always equal to `i + IDM_LAST`. Therefore, you can replace that `for` with this one:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size && i + IDM_LAST < IDM_LAST + MAXLASTUSEDDEST; i++)
{
    menuAPopup.AppendMenu(MF_STRING, i + IDM_LAST, m_Last.ElementAt(i));
}
```

Simplifying:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size && i < MAXLASTUSEDDEST; i++)
{
    menuAPopup.AppendMenu(MF_STRING, i + IDM_LAST, m_Last.ElementAt(i));
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using 2 variables and just use 1?

Comment: If the variables are dependent, i.e. you can express one in terms of the other, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 termination conditions: `i < size` and `j < IDM_LAST + MAXLASTUSEDDEST`. Now: how would you rewrite the `i < size` in terms of `j`? Once you've got that, you should be able to similarly replace `i` in the loop body, in terms of `j`.

Note that both `i` and `j` always increment by 1 on each iteration. Because of your initializations, this means that in each iteration: `j == (i + IDM_LAST)` is true.

Now as for the given loop, it's not correct as it is: you're using the comma operator in your terminating condition, which won't do what you want: the result of `i < size` will be ignored! Change the loop to:

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0, j = IDM_LAST; (i < size) && (j < IDM_LAST + MAXLASTUSEDDEST); i++, j++)
```

Comment: (Well, `i` *is* used in the body of the loop.)

Comment: yep..so there is no such way right?I have to have 2 variables?

Comment: @user1563551 I think you can do it with only one

Answer (score 0):

```
 CStringArray m_Last;
 int size = m_Last.GetCount();

 // In the .h file I have,

 // last of the contiguous Resource block ID's
 #define IDM_LAST 90
 // there are 5 Resource IDs only
 const int MAXLAST = 5;

 for (int i=0 ; (i<size)&&(i<MAXLAST) ; i++)
 {
    menuAPopup.AppendMenu(MF_STRING, (IDM_LAST - i), m_Last.ElementAt(i));
 }
```